# GWT + Spring MVC on Eclipse Virgo OSGi

Tags: gwt, spring-mvc, osgi

I'm making my first steps on GWT. I want to run my GWT application on JSP that are generated with spring MVC. Spring MVC is hosted on Eclipse virgo which provides an OSGi context.

So :

- How can I use GWt and spring MVC at the same time ? (I guess that I must include js in a jsp right ?)
- Use GWT debugger + spring MVC on server ? (Lunch 2 servers ? one for GWT and the other for Virgo ?)

Answer (score 0):

GWT apps are normally run as one-page apps, meaning that the page is not reloaded (URL in your browsers is always the same - except for the part after #). For example this is how Gmail works (look at the URL in your browser).

Spring MVC is a classical web app - on every click page is reloaded with a new page.

In this sense Spring MVC and GWT do not work well together. You could shoehorn them together, but this would not be a natural fit.

Comment: thank you for your response. Actually I had just to run GWT with noserver. I added a jar file which contain a servlet that can be used for my GWT remote services